# In a C++ application in Mac or Windows, is there a way to determine if a given ProcessId still exists?

Tags: c++, process

I have a QT application that runs on both Windows and Mac. Is there a way  to provide a PID, and get back:

1. If the PID exists
2. The name of the process under that PID

For Windows I thing I can use `EnumProcesses()` to find out what I need, but how can this be done on Mac?

Comment: There's no such thing like a _platform agnostic_ process ID.

Comment: On Mac, I guess `kill(pid, 0);` would work

Comment: @TedLyngmo: Consider writing answer?

Comment: @Joshua I've never programmed on a Mac so I don't know for sure. I was just guessing.

Comment: If you are not sure that a process with a given ID still exist, you will also ne be unsure if you find a process that is the expected one if the ID is reused.

Answer (score 0):

So it's a QT question. That constrains the space enough that I can provide an answer for the most reasonable case.

A good portable program probably does not monitor arbitrary processes but only its own; and for that everything is well in hand. Child processes are spawned using the `QProcess` class, and it provides of itself what you need in the form of the `stateChanged` signal. You don't ever ask if the process ID is good; you get told when it's no longer good.

If you insist on checking if the PID is good; you're in luck. If `/proc/self` exists but `/proc/${pid}` doesn't than the PID isn't good anymore. This works about as well as `EnumProcesses` on windows. You can get the process name from `/proc/${pid}/exe` (it's a symbolic link, so call `readlink()` on it). If `/proc/self` doesn't exist, you probably can't enum processes because the system is in a degenerate state.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <libproc.h>


bool is_process_active_by_pid(pid_t pid , char * exe_path)
{
    int ret;
    char pathbuf[PROC_PIDPATHINFO_MAXSIZE];
    bool is_active;
    ret = proc_pidpath (pid, pathbuf, sizeof(pathbuf));
    if ( ret <= 0 ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "PID %d: proc_pidpath ();\n", pid);
        fprintf(stderr, "    %s\n", strerror(errno));
        is_active = false;
    } else {
        printf("proc %d: %s\n", pid, pathbuf);
        is_active = true;
        strcpy(exe_path , pathbuf);
    }
    return is_active;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

On Windows:

> If the PID exists

You can use `OpenProcess()` for it, giving it the desired PID.  You have to do this anyway for the next step, so there is no point in wasting time using `EnumProcesses()` at all.

> The name of the process under that PID

Once you have opened a `HANDLE` to the process, you can use `GetModuleFileNameEx()`, `GetProcessImageFileName()`, or `QueryFullProcessImageName()` to get the full path and filename to the process.  If you want a more human-readable display name, you can pass that path+filename to `GetFileVersionInfo()` and `VerQueryValue()` to query its display name.  Or, use the path+file with `EnumServiceStatus()` and `QueryServiceConfig()` to find a matching SCM service and get its display name.

Comment: Need to say how on a Mac to answer question. Your Windows advise is good, but it's not the question.